# h3 shifting after it fades in or out

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been finishing up this website redesign and wanted to add some fun new functions into it. I have a contact form nested in the footer to keep it out of sight but, not out of mind. :p I have the script working very well and the `fadeToggle` does the trick just fine but the main header, acting as the click element, seems to twitch side to side when activated. I am only hiding the `li` and not the `ul` or `h3` so I am not to sure why it's moving. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! This is not life or death to me but it does annoy the hell out of me ha.

[Live site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/redesign/)

[jsFiddle before fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/utFsR/)

[jsFiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/utFsR/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="formS">
    <span class="footerT">© Copyright 2013 Ohio Association of Health Underwriters</span>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <ul>
        <h4>Contact Us (click here)</h4>
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Submission" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html" />
        <li><label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></li>

        <li><label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"></li>

        <li><label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city"></li>

        <li><label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"></li>

        <li><label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></li>

        <li><label for="comments">I would like to know:</label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></li>

        <li><button name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button></li>

        <input type="hidden" name="form_order" value="alpha"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_delivery" value="hourly_digest"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_format" value="text"/>
      </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Contact form page */

.formS {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

form > ul           {
font-size: 18px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: right;
    list-style-type:none;
}

form > ul > li {
padding: 5px;
display: none;
}

form { 
text-align:left; 
padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
height: 408px;
}

.formS > form > ul > li > label     {
float: left;
width: 50px;
margin:5px 10px 0 0;
text-align:right;
display:block;
background:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border-radius: 5px;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #2b2b2b;
}

textarea {
width: 150px; 
height: 50px;
border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
padding:5px; 
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #2b2b2b inset;
resize: vertical;
}

.formS > form > ul > li > input {
width: 150px; 
height: 15px;
border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
padding:5px; 
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #2b2b2b inset;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('form ul h4').on('click', function() { 
    $('form > ul > li').stop(true).fadeToggle(1500); 
});
```

(P.S. I do know that input tags can not go inside a `ul` and am currently fixing the previous developers mistakes on this contact form >.>. At least I only had to deal with myself for the rest of this site's design/development!)

Comment: It's better to add a fiddle isolating the issue than a link to your live site, so that future users will be able to benefit from it when your site changes (and so it is easier for problem solvers).

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future ref. I am doing this at work so I was trying to use as little company time as possible. I'll add a fiddle of this in a sec!

Comment: Just added a fiddle with beginning and fixed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the `<ul>` is determined by the visible items inside it.  You need to specify a width on the `<ul>` that is as wide as the fully visible version of the contact form.  For example:

```
form > ul {
    width: 240px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million mate! I did not expect it to be something as simple as a width setting.

Answer (score 1):

Your header is left-aligned, and revealing the form widens the parent element, expanding it to the left. Try right-aligning the header - then it will stay right aligned no matter how wide the container becomes.

Comment: Your answer also worked but the set width allowed me to keep the structure just as I designed it.